# Calling a function in Magento Admin Module Controller via URL

Tags: php, magento, model-view-controller, magento-1.7

I was under the impression (after viewing some tutorials on Alan Storms site about [Models](http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm)) that I should be able to call a function on my controller via a url like so:

```
http://www.localhost.com:8080/magento/index.php/mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule/someFunction
```

and in the controller declare:

```
public function someFunctionAction()
{
    Mage::log("Im In");
}
```

The problem is that nothing is being logged. Is there something special with admin modules that prevents this from working?

Note: I haven't included the rest of my code for declaring the module as everything is working fine, I am merely curious about calling the controller function via the Url in this way but please let me know if you require more information in order to answer it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call your action with the direct URL, because Magento uses nonces in the admin section. You can read about this here: http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited , look for the "Magento Admin URLs"-section.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if your controller name is poductController than in URL use product

```
http://www.localhost.com:8080/magento/index.php/mymodule/product/someFunction
```

Comment: As @petergunn explained above, this isn't possible.

Comment: Comon man without even trying how could say it is not possible

Comment: okay no pob, you can even check this blog

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch

Comment: That article was written by Alan Storm and only applies to the front end. Not the admin section of Magento.

Comment: okay.. thanks for bringing to my attention.. if you dont mind can you look at this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664794/fieldset-in-system-configuration-magento-admin-module